# .formula changing string how to fix?

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do below is a special copy past where it pastes the named range instead of the range.
I select the cell I want to paste in one workbook and then select the cell I want to copy in the other, then run the macro.

The issue here is when I do  C.Formula = String2, it changes the string name

- Namedrange result--`Dog`
- String1 result--`=[testA.xlsx]Sheet1!`
- String2 result--`=[testA.xlsx]Sheet1!Dog`

but after the formula gets set to `=testA.xlsx!Dog`

Whats wrong here?
Also is there a better way of pasting a link with the named range?

```
Sub Macro7()

     Dim Namedrange As String

     Namedrange = ActiveCell.Name.Name
     Selection.Copy
     ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
     ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True


     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

     For Each C In Selection
     endstring = InStr(C.Formula, "!")
     String1 = Left(C.Formula, endstring)
     String2 = String1 + Namedrange
     MsgBox endstring
     MsgBox String1
     MsgBox String2
     C.Formula = String2
     Next

     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has nothing to do with the code. What worked was that I changed the named range scope to the current sheet so the named range result now is "Sheet1!Dog"